# How do I delete " in every cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my spreadsheet there are descriptions that use <kbd>"</kbd>.

For example

```
3" plates
```

I need to delete the <kbd>"</kbd> in all cells that it's in.

Answer (score 3):

Use "Replace All" feature to remove '"' character from the spreadsheet.

Press Ctrl+H to open the "Find and Replace" dialog box.

Enter " in the "Find What" box and do nothing in the "Replace With" box. Now click on "Replace All" button.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: You beat me too it haha I had to sign in first